# Java validation beans: Validate enum field values

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm used to use validation rules in order to check my rest parameters:

```
public class ConfigurationParameterForm {

    private @NotEmpty String name;
    private @NotNull Object value;
    private @NotEmpty String beanProperty;
    private @NotEmpty String type;

}
```

When `type` field must be one of these enum values:

```
public enum ParameterType {
    A("API"), B("BackOffice"), F("FrontOffice"), Q("Quartz"), S("Servlet");

    private String description;

    ParameterType(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

So, I'd like to check that `type` only contains valid values, I mean `A`, `B`, `F`, `Q`, `S`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just change the type of the `type` field from `String` to `ParameterType` and Spring will do the conversion automatically and will throw an exception if the given string does not match any of the names of the enum constants.

Comment: I need to provide a custom validation message...

Comment: Catch the exception...